# Header not appearing in IE 7...what could be wrong?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

As usual, we have an issue in IE.

For whatever reason, the header is not appearing at ALL in IE7.

http://stevens.usc.edu/innovationatUSC/

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: And if you correct the 185 errors that the W3 validator finds, does it work then?

Comment: No JavaScript errors.  And I looked through the 185 errors that the W3 validator finds, and unfortunately they are all beyond my control (WP plugins and user errors).  Thanks for the thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code in the head element:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, you should add as part of your css reset a 'display:block' for all html5 elements so that IE knows they are block elements:

```
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}
```

Comment: the shiv doesn't need the display:block part I think

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't understand HTML5 elements, you need a "shiv", here's where you can find it: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: well, it should solve it :) I mean, that's the problem's cause, 100%, just make sure the script is loaded. To begin with, remove the if conditional and load it for all browsers. If this works, then it means your conditional is not correct.

Comment: or just replace <header> with <div class="header"> and change your CSS accordingly - same with <nav> ...

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Dive Into Html 5 the  tag is not supported by default in IE7.

http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width on the header element.

You have a ".header {width:960px)" in your stylesheet but this isn't affecting the header element as it's not a class so it should just be "header {width:960px)".

It should probably inherit the width from it's parent element #page, but with IE you just never know.